# Centralized configuration service

Tags: configuration, architecture, soa

We have a system that has multiple processes running of different physical servers. Some in Java, others in C++. Each has its own config file where the database connection string is maintained.   We need to keep the DB and server name in the config file of every program. The password has to be encrypted. Every program has to perform the task of reading its config and decrypting the password and then connecting to the DB.

Is there a pattern that solves this problem? Ideally I would like all global configuration to be in a single place and all programs running on different physical servers. What is the best way to do this?

Regards,

Yash

Comment: use the "private public keys" pattern as knwon from ssh, to have each application logon to a service on the database server, and request the password on an encrypted tunnel..
This way you only maintain the password on the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Every program has to perform the task of reading its config and
>   decrypting the password and then connecting to the DB.

Since your software itself decrypts a password, hacker will be able to recover encryption details from your binary and use them to decrypt password from configuration file.

This problem is usually solved using three-tier architecture. You write an intermediary **Application Server** which does database connections. Your client applications then connect to this application server using login and password of users, not those of the database. Application Server verifies user's credentials and controls access.